# Does this nonlinear differential equation have a closed form solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology

I have a differential equation inspired by a population dynamics problem and I'm don't know how to solve it. I wonder if anyone here can tell me if a closed form solution exists and how to find it.

$$ 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = p(t)u(t) - k
$$

Where $p$ is the concentration of (non-replenishing) food, $u$ is a population, and $k$ is the rate at which members of the population die. Since $p$ is non-replenishing,

$$
p(t) = p_0 - \int^t_0 u(\tau) d\tau
$$

Combining these equations gives the differential equation

$$
\left( p_0 - \int^t_0 u(\tau) d\tau \right)u(t) - \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - k = 0
$$

How do I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure it is not $…-k·u(t)$? Because at the moment, you have the same amount dying if it is a population of 10 and of 10000000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you make the death rate into a real rate, you can write your equations as
$$
\dot u=pu-ku\\
\dot p=-u
$$
and by differentiating the second the first equation becomes
$$
-\ddot p = -p\dot p+k\dot p
$$
which can be integrated to
$$
\dot p =\frac12 p^2 - kp + C
$$
which can be solved as the $\arctan$ or $\text{Artanh}$ depending on $C$.

Comment: Are you sure the solution is of the form arctan? My CAS gives me the solution p(t) = (2*C-k^2)^(1/2) * tan(((c1 + t)*(2*C-k^2)^(1/2))/2) + k.

Comment: Should have continued that, the intermediate solution after integrating the separated equation is something like $\arctan(A+Bp)=C+Dt$ translating into $p=(\tan(C+Dt)-A)/B$. Meaningful solutions should be with the hyperbolic tangent, since that has bounded asymptotics.